# How to reserve internet bandwidth for a server (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, internet, bandwidth

How to reserve internet bandwidth for a server? I know I can limit bandwidth but I want to do the opposite thing. What I mean by that is I want to have always reserved 200Mb/s of upload and download for my server.

For example some devices use the bandwidth but then the server won't have enough what is 200Mb/s. Then I want to access the server with 200Mb/s or more if is available but the 200Mb/s is the reserved amount if anything else uses the internet bandwidth I want.

Comment: Ubuntu Server 22.04 but I might change it.

Comment: Unless your Ubuntu server is the gateway to the internet, I would say this hasn't really anything to do with Ubuntu. This sounds more like a networking issue, with isolating traffic etc. which is done on your networking hardware. You could try and ask questions about networking configuration on [su].

Comment: And in general you probably don't want to do this either; you may want some sort of QoS, but bandwidth reservation tends to lead to over all worse performance of everything.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking some QoS might be a better solution, but I'm no export in networking. 

Comment: Alright, Thanks for you answers!